# Classify pixels using deep learning is giving wrong result for Landsat-7 data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-pro, landsat-8, land-cover, landsat-7, deep-learning

I am trying to classify two LULC maps from two data. One is for 2020 (Landsat 8), and another is for 2000 (Landsat 7). The pixel depth is 64-bit and both of the data were downloaded from Google Earth Engine. I am using a deep learning model from ESRI and Classify Pixels Using Deep Learning tools in ArcGIS to get the LULC data.

I have tried and successfully generated a LULC map for Landsat8 data. But the generated LULC map from the landsat7 is showing inconsistency.
[image: LULC of Landsat7]

I have used the same method as the Landsat8. The LULC of landsat8 looks like this:
[image: LULC of Landsat8]

As a beginner, I have tried but couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: Seems like LS7 is classified as open water? Can you share the model used for LS7? Is it the same for LS8?

Comment: It is the same model. The link to the model:
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e732ee81a9c14c238a14df554a8e3225

Comment: Just an assumption but the bands of Landsat 7 and Landsat 8 differ in wavelength, the amount of bands and the order of bands as to how they are stored inside the file. Since this model is specifically designed for Landsat 8 you might be out of luck here.

Comment: Indeed, the band ordering is different too. For example NIR is band 4 in L7, but B5 in L8

Comment: I have tried generating LULC from a single band. I chose Band 3 (0.53-0.59 μm) for Landsat 8 and Band 2 (0.52-0.60 μm) for Landsat 7. The result is still the same.

Comment: Your classification with Band 3 from Landsat 8 yields the same results as with all bands? Or just that L7 still is all water? Also shouldn't the scenes be in 16bit, thats atleast what the ESRI doc is talking about. Might have smth to do with that.

Comment: Classification from Band 3 yields almost similar results. The problem is with the landsat 7 data. Both of the data are in 64-bit format.

Comment: Well if you check the same pixel in L7 and L8, preferably from something that should stay the same after your classification, how do the values differ? If it varies by a lot then I suppose the GEE 16-bit to 64-bit alteration may have given different results for L7 and L8. If that is not the case it is probably some deep learning black box mystery.

Comment: The only reason that comes to mind is that the ML was only trained with Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS.

Comment: @Ash you are correct. We had to take an alternate approach

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that comes to mind is that the ML was only trained with Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS.